# Get detailed watch time data from YouTube endpoints

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-analytics-api

I'm looking to create a piece of software that sends requests to YouTube's server on behalf of the user and organizes the watch time data nicely into charts

So far, I have come up with the following:

```js
async function getYouTubeAnalyticsData(result: GoogleTokensResult) {
  // https://developers.google.com/youtube/analytics/content_owner_reports
  const params = {
    dimensions: "day",
    startDate: "2023-07-01",
    endDate: "2023-08-02",
    ids: "channel==MINE",
    // https://developers.google.com/youtube/analytics/metrics
    metrics: "views,estimatedMinutesWatched,averageViewDuration,averageViewPercentage"
  };

  const searchParams = new URLSearchParams(params);

  // https://developers.google.com/youtube/analytics/reference/reports/query
  const response = await fetch(`https://youtubeanalytics.googleapis.com/v2/reports?${searchParams}`, {
    headers: {
      Authorization: `Bearer ${result.access_token}`
    }
  });
  return response.json();
}
```

The problem is that I only get a basic report
In this case, the output shape returned by `getYouTubeAnalyticsData` is:

```js
{
  "columnHeaders": [
    {"name": "day", "columnType": "DIMENSION", "dataType": "STRING"},
    {"name": "channel", "columnType": "DIMENSION", "dataType": "STRING"},
    {"name": "views", "columnType": "METRIC", "dataType": "INTEGER"},
    {"name": "estimatedMinutesWatched", "columnType": "METRIC", "dataType": "INTEGER"},
    {"name": "averageViewDuration", "columnType": "METRIC", "dataType": "INTEGER"},
    {"name": "averageViewPercentage", "columnType": "METRIC", "dataType": "FLOAT"},
  ],
  "kind": "youtubeAnalytics#resultTable",
  "rows": [
    ["2023-07-01", "CHANNEL_ID", 27, 39, 87, 11.95],
    [...]
  ]
}
```

Instead, I'm looking to get much deeper data, for example:

1. In day 1, the user watched 100s in channel A and 200s in channel B
2. In day 2, the user watched 300s in channel C and 400s in channel D

Comment: This api is very limited.  Your also not going to get anything more then 90 days old.

Comment: Thank you for your information! Can I possibly use other YouTube APIs that will give me the data I seek?

Comment: There is no other api